# How to get a remote server posted JSON?

Tags: 7

A remote server will redirect with posting a JSON string back to a URL in my Drupal site defined by hook_menu. But I don't know either care the URL of the remote server. How can I get the JSON data in my hook_menu? 
I use these codes:

```
      $received = file_get_contents("drupal://input"); // Use inputstream module.
      $received = json_decode($received, TRUE);
      dpm($received);
```

When the redirection happened, the hook_menu page shows nothing. When I thereafter access the frontpage of my Drupal site, it shows as below:

Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "drupal" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in shisuepay_postback() (line 130 of /.../sites/all/modules/custom/shisuepay/shisuepay.module).

Warning: file_get_contents(drupal://input): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in shisuepay_postback() (line 130 of /.../sites/all/modules/custom/shisuepay/shisuepay.module).

Comment: I'm having a small problem understanding your question, I assume English is not your first language? Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to do?

Why are you using hook_menu to do this?

Comment: What's `drupal://input`? Do you mean `php://input`, as in the raw request data excluding headers?

Comment: Yes, it should be php://input other than drupal://input

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the postback data is not the format of JSON. So I just use $_POST variable to get the data. Thank you all the same.